# Dynamically Change Element's Children's Attributes Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://liveweave.com/8YMXow

I have a select element with the class `.selected`. I want to detect how many options it has (Which I believe I'd have to use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)), and be able to manipulate the select options display similar to how [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) handles their lists.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about.
[image]

I can use :nth-child to handle the values and display text, but my problem is getting the option[length] to show as textboxes that way I can change their values one by one. (I'm not asking about drag&drop sorting. I want to do that myself therefore it's irrelevant in this post. If I need to I'll make a separate post for that)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hmcp = $(".how-many-changable-properties");
  hmcp.html( $(".selected option").length );
  
  inputTxt = $("<input type=\"text\">");
  
  $(".options").html( $(".selected option").length + " " + inputTxt);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="how-many-changable-properties"></span>
    <div class="options"></div>
    
    <select class="selected">
      <option value="apples">apples</option>
      <option value="bananas">bananas</option>
      <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: On Sourceforge I can manipulate a list as seen in the picture provided in the OP. I'm trying to figure out how to do that for a select element. I want to grab it's values[length] and manipulate each one as seen in the screenshot above. I just haven't figured out how to do it. Hence why I'm asking here.

Comment: ***manipulate as seen in the picture/screenshot*** does not say very much; maybe some description would be helpful.

Comment: I want to grab the select element's option's values, display them in an array as an input[type=text] and change whatever value I want that way via keyup for easy manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hmcp = $(".how-many-changable-properties");
    hmcp.html( $(".selected option").length );
    var inpt = $('<input type="text" />');
  
    $('.selected option').each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        inpt.clone().val( this.value ).add( $('<br/>') ).on('input', function() {
            that.val( this.value ).text( this.value );
        })
        .appendTo( '.options' );
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span class="how-many-changable-properties"></span>
    <div class="options"></div>
    
    <select class="selected">
      <option value="apples">apples</option>
      <option value="bananas">bananas</option>
      <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: That was fast. I didn't think about .each I was thinking about .length or .children. Thanks

Comment: Great! Glad you found this helpful.